# Convert monitor resolution to rows and cols?

Tags: python, shell, terminal

Convert monitor resolution to rows and cols .

The follow code is what i have thus far

```
python << EOF
import subprocess
import sys
results = subprocess.Popen(['xrandr'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split("current")[1].split(",")[0]
width = results.split("x")[0].strip()
height = results.split("x")[1].strip()
print width + "x" + height

row = width
col = height
sys.stdout.write("\x1b[8;{rows};{cols}t".format(rows=row, cols=col))

print """
      TEST
      """
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the *dtterm* window manipulation controls (see [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps;Ps;Ps-t.1EB0)), the terminal may implement the corresponding *reports*.  This section has the information:

```
CSI Ps ; Ps ; Ps t
          Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions).
          These controls may be disabled using the allowWindowOps
          resource.  Valid values for the first (and any additional
          parameters) are:
```

This is relevant:

```
        Ps = 1 4  -> Report xterm window in pixels.
      Result is CSI  4  ;  height ;  width t
```

That is, you could obtain the size of the window in *pixels* using that control sequence, and from knowing the window's rows/columns, you could compute the font-size.  Given that information (and the monitor's size), you can determine the number of character rows and columns which would fit.